# Dump memory use memcpy occurred error

Tags: android, c, memory, memcpy

I want dump memory use memcpy. 
I want hex dump memory range 0x400b5000 ~ 0x400fd000

I got this memory range from "cat /proc/[pid]/maps"

[image]

But It occurred Error like this,

```
SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x11)) `
```

My Code  like this.

```
void dumpCode( char* start, char* end, char* subject  )
{
    FILE* fp;
    char fileName[100];

    void* s = (void*)0x400b5000;
    void* e = (void*)0x400fd000;

    char buf[4];

    sprintf( fileName, "/storage/emulated/0/test/%s-%s.txt", start,end );

    if ((fp = fopen( fileName, "w" )) == NULL)
        printf("Error: Could not open '%s'\n", fileName);

    while( s <= e ){
        memcpy( buf, s, sizeof(int) );
        fwrite( buf, sizeof(int), 1, fp );
        s++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

How can I dump the memory range?

Can anyone suggest solution in my situation? or some proper Documents..?

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: I don't know if it will solve anything, or what the purpose of your program is, but you don't need the temporary buffer `buf` or the loop. Just write directly from the memory: `fwrite(s, 1, e - s, fp);`

Comment: Also, your error handling if the file can not be opened is not very good. You will still continue the function if `fp` is a null pointer, and have *undefined behavior* when you try to use that null pointer.

Comment: This code is poorly written. `s++` isn't a standard code, but rather a compiler extension; use `char*`. You're not dealing with the fact that `fclose(fp)` can get a NULL pointer. `subject` isn't used at all. Also, give us more information about the line that causes the segfault.